# How to distribute yb-masters in multi-region deployment in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

In terms of numbers of yb-master, they should be as many as the replication factor. My question is, is having master and servers running in all the nodes a bad policy?

And, if we have a multidc deployment, should we have at least 1 master on each dc?
I guess the best is to accommodate the leader of yb-master in DC, which is going to be the main workload (if there is any) right?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly normal to colocate an yb-tserver and yb-master in the same server. But in large deployments, it's better for them to be on separate servers for splitting workloads (so heavy usage on yb-tserver won't interfere with yb-master).

And, if you have a multidc deployment, then you should deploy 1 in each region, so that you have region failover for the yb-masters too.
For a situation with YB to be usable, you have to have 2 out of 3 masters, so indeed with a 2DC situation, you cannot build a situation where you always have availability, because you have to have 2 masters at one place and 1 at the other. So the only solution for high availability is 3DC.
Do 3DC with the same number of nodes in each DC, so you will end up with a total of 3, 6, 9, etc. nodes.A master should be in each D.C., if not you will again lose resilience.

> I guess the best is to accommodate the leader of yb-master in DC,
> which is going to be the main workload (if there is any) right?

In this case you can set 1 region/zone as the preferred one and the database will try to put leaders there automatically using `set-preferred-zones` https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#set-preferred-zones